# How to delete fraction of rows that has specific attribute value from pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Having a pandas data frame, how can I efficiently delete a fraction of rows that has a specific value, say,  "*low*" in the attribute *class*?
here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(3)
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3,4], "b":[5,6,7,8], "class":['High','Low','Low','Low']})
drop_indices = np.random.choice(df.index, int(np.ceil(0.5*df.shape[0])) , replace=True)
df_subset = df.drop(drop_indices)
print df
print df_subset
```

output:

```
   a  b class
0  1  5  High
1  2  6   Low
2  3  7   Low
3  4  8   Low
   a  b class
1  2  6   Low
3  4  8   Low
```

This delete from all classes, I want it to delete from the class=*Low* only.

Comment: Could you 1. Post sample data 2. Expected output 3. What you've tried so far 4. Code please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filter down to just rows you want to delete from, use [`sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sample.html) to select the fraction of members to remove, then use [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) to remove them:

```
df = df.drop(df[df['class'] == 'Low'].sample(frac=0.33).index)
```

The resulting output:

```
   a  b class
0  1  5  High
2  3  7   Low
3  4  8   Low
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different way of looking at it would use boolean slicing, keeping all the non-Low rows and then keeping only a fraction of the Low rows through a 0-1 random number.

```
df[(df['class'] != 'Low') | (np.random.rand(len(df)) < .33)]
```